# no puedo centrar estos elementos con css

Tags: css, reactjs, css3

estoy tratando de organizar este html (hecho en next) y no puedo hacer que las cajas se alinien como yo quiero.

Para empezar, este seria el html que me da problemas:

```
<div className={style.proyectos} id="Proyectos">
      <Image
          src={project}
          alt="proyectos"
          height={400}
          width={400}
          className={style.proyectos_img}
        />

        <h2 className={style.proyectos_h2}>Proyectos:</h2>
        
        <div className={style.proyectos_catalogo}>
          <div className={style.proyectos_ejemplos}></div>
          <div className={style.proyectos_ejemplos}></div>
          <div className={style.proyectos_ejemplos}></div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
```

Como pueden ver es un html muy sencillo, lo que intento hacer es lo siguiente, arriva de todo la izquierda este el nombre **'Proyecto'**, debajo de **'proyecto'**,poner la **imagen** (la imagen tiene una resolucionde 400px 400px), y toda la mitad derecha debe estar ocupada por el contenedor: `<div className={style.proyectos_ejemplos}></div>` para que la gente pueda ver mis proyectos. pero por mas que trato no lo logro, si muevo algo lo otro no funciona, y viceversa.

Intente por todos los medios hacer lo que describo pero no me sale,sencillamente no logro hacerlo, quizas mis metodologias son erroneas. les dejo mi css:

```
.proyectos {
  height: 100vh;
  color: var(--white);
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    var(--A) 30%,
    var(--B) 45%,
    var(--C) 70%,
    var(--D) 80%,
    var(--E) 85%,
    var(--F) 90%,
    var(--G) 100%
  );
}

.proyectos_contenedor {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 4px;
}

.proyectos_h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: -21rem;
  max-width: 6rem;
}

.proyectos_catalogo {
  margin-top: 9rem;
}

.proyectos_ejemplos {
  background-color: var(--G);
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid var(--H);
  width: 45vw;
  height: 15vh;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Debe ser en orden: primero el título `proyectos_h2`, tiene que estar primero. Y creo que está demaciado arriba con `-21rem`. Luego del título debe estar la imagen.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, si mi css esta justamtene porque no encontraba formas mejores de llegar a lo que quiero y empeze a inventar cosas, vere si tu respuesta me es util